# What is settimeout proper syntax?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Hi I'm trying to use settimeout but gets an erro "Call to undefined function setTimeout() in". I based my code on w3schools. Here's my code:

```
<?php

function compareperc(){
    echo "hello";
}

setTimeout(compareperc(), 1000);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `set_time_limit ()`. See more details here http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: You are confusing PHP and JavaScript

Comment: `setTimeout` isn't a PHP function as far as I know. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is syntactically valid JavaScript and syntactically valid PHP. It threw me for a loop, ha.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, oh well. You gotta have a tough skin on this site ^_^

Comment: *"I based my code on w3schools."* I suggest [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead. Generally more reliable, less burdened with ads.

Comment: I'm trying to call a settimeout which is a javascript inside a php code. Is using javascript possible inside php? I badly need the settimeout function @T.J Crowder

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie I'm trying to learn. Sorry I can't match your superior skills @naomik

Comment: @Newboy11 no need to apologize! Are you trying to delay the execution of a function using PHP? I was confused because I saw you using `setTimeout`, which is a JavaScript function. It's easy enough to get the lines crossed because, syntactically, PHP and JavaScript have many similarities.

Comment: Yup that's what I needed to delay the execution of function in php. Is there other alternative?@naomik

Answer (score 1):

To delay execution in PHP, you can use the following code:

```
<?php

function compareperc(){
    echo "hello";
}

sleep(1);
compareperc();

?>
```

I wouldn't necessarily say it's advisable, but this would be the equivalent without trying to use JavaScript where it won't work.

Comment: This is a nice alternative.